# Re-defining already assigned python class

Tags: python, oop, inner-classes

I am new to Python and I inherited someone's code that had the following code structure. Why do I get an object not callable and how can I redefine this method again even after re-assigning l.bar. Another question would therefore be what's the difference between l.bar and l.bar()?

```
>>> class foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.name = "Food"
...     class bar(object):
...         def __init__(self):
...             self.name = "Is"
...         class tea(object):
...             def __init__(self):
...                 self.name = "Good"
...     
>>> l = foo()
>>> m = l.bar()   
>>> m.name = "Was"
>>> l.bar = m
>>> r = l.bar()  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bar' object is not callable
```

Comment: `bar` is not a member of a `foo` instance. `bar` identifier is `foo.bar`.

Comment: The only good reason to have nested classes is to make a second-class pun.

Comment: @wim - I Still get the same 'bar' object is not callable

Comment: @Harrison. The code is supposed to have subclasses

Comment: @Carly.J: those are not subclasses, so if it's supposed to have subclasses then someone is confused, either the original author or you.

Comment: why the downvotes, though?

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, it's generally not good practice to have nested classes. But, here's a breakdown of what's happening:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Food"

    class bar(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.name = "Is"

        class tea(object):
            def __init__(self):
                self.name = "Good"


l = foo()  # l is now an instance of foo
print l.name  # "Food"
m = l.bar()  # m is now an instance of bar
print m.name  # "Is"
m.name = "Was"  # you've assigned m's name to "Was"
print m.name  # "Was"
l.bar = m  # you are overriding foo's nested bar class now with an instance of bar
print l.name  # "Food"
print l.bar  # <__main__.bar object at 0x108371ad0>: this is now an instance, not a class
print l.bar.name  # "Was"
r = l.bar()  # you are now trying to call an instance of bar
```

The last line doesn't work because of the same reasons calling `l()` or `foo()()` doesn't work.

If you *absolutely must* figure out a way to make foo.bar().name return something else, you can create a new class and reassign foo.bar to it. But, this is really gross and not recommended. Hopefully, you can just change that original code.

```
print foo.bar().name  # "Is"

class NewBar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Was'
foo.bar = NewBar

print foo.bar().name  # "Was"
```

Comment: *but that attribute does not exist in your code* : Not true. The reason it doesn't exist in the **your** code is because `__init__(..)` overwrites it with a string. Class variables are certainly available to instances.

Comment: You're right - I was being silly. Updated answer to try to explain what's actually going on :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Why do i get an object not callable

You assigned `l.bar` to be an instance of the class `foo.bar` (specifically, you assigned `m` to it). Instances of that class aren't callable, therefore `l.bar` isn't callable.

> how can i redefine this method again even after re-assigning l.bar

Maybe this advice is too obvious, but don't re-assign `l.bar`.

However, you can reset `l.bar` so that it refers to the method it originally referred to, by doing `del l.bar`.

The reason this works is because if the individual object has no `bar` attribute of its own, then Python looks next to see whether its class has an attribute of the same name. So, to begin with the expression `l.bar` evaluates to the class `foo.bar`, since `l` has type `foo`. Then you assigned `l` a `bar` attribute of its own, so `l.bar` suddenly starts evaluating to that object instead. You can restore normality by deleting the object's own attribute.

> what's the difference between l.bar and l.bar()

`l.bar` just gets the value of the attribute `bar` from the object `l` (or from its class, if the object `l` doesn't have one of its own, as explained above. If that fails too it'd go to base classes). `l.bar()` gets the value of that attribute and then calls it. `()` at this position means a function call, so the thing you put it after had better be callable.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear which of the following problems you are experiencing:

## 1. indentation issue

When copy-pasting from source to terminal, indentation sometimes gets messed up. in ipython you can use `%paste` to safely paste code.

The correctly indented class declarations are:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Food"
class bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Is"
class tea(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Good"
```

But then the other commands make no sense.

## 2. instance is not the same as class

When defining a class inside a class, you have to use the outer class name to "get" to the inner class name. I.e.:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Food"
    class bar(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.name = "Is"
        class tea(object):
            def __init__(self):
                self.name = "Good"

foo_inst = foo()
bar_inst = foo.bar()
tea_inst = foo.bar.tea()
```

Anyhow, these lines still make not much sense:

```
>>> l.bar = m
>>> r = l.bar()
```

Why would you want to override `bar` which is (was) a class name...

Comment: I'm solving problem 2. The original intent was not to over-ride or delete the class object but to get rid of additional objects that were carried with m.